# PHP script returns error/nothing when fetching data with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a PHP file called 'myProxy.php' sitting on my server that looks like this:

```
<?php
 echo "text";
 exit();
?>
```

When I try to get that string from the file with an AJAX call that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.mydomain.com/myProxy.php",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
     alert("Horray!");
  }
 });
```

The script turns absolutely nothing and I get a red error icon in the Firebug console. Does anyone know what might be causing this? Perhaps a setting is not set somewhere?

Comment: Any error messages? What do you see when you open the `myProxy.php` file directly in your browser? Why are you using the full URI? Non-JSONP calls should be on the same domain and therefore, the URI should be relative

Comment: No, it's just empty response with the red 'X' error. If I just straight visit the page in a browser, it outputs the text just fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you mean by "Non-JSONP calls should be on the same domain and therefore, the URI should be relative" or perhaps link me to a source with more information? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling you're running into a *same origin policy* restriction.

For plain old AJAX, your script and resource should exist on the same domain. If this is actually the case, you can simply use

```
$.get("/myProxy.php", function(data) {
    alert("Hooray!");
}, "text");
```

If you truly need cross-domain support, you can change your PHP script to respond to [JSONP requests](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp)

```
<?php
// myProxy.php
$callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : 'callback';
$data = array('text' => 'text');
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
printf('%s(%s)', $callback, json_encode($data));
```

... and the JavaScript

```
$.getJSON("http://www.domain.com/myProxy.php?callback=?", function(data) {
    alert(data.text);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Phil. This was immensely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can't place your script on another domain/subdomain/protocol than your current script is

Comment: Interesting, I am embarrassed to say that I was not aware of this. What would a simple workaround be?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not very clear on what this implies. So, the reason it doesn't work is because my javascript is not being executed on the same server that the myProxy.php file is on? But when it javascript ever executed from a server? I thought it was client-side only. Unless I fundamentally don't understand something...