# how can I handle the append() method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that called redirect.php, this page has several attributes that I want to send them to another page, actually I write this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({        
            url: "http://www.mysite.com/getdata.php",
            context: document.body,
            success: function(data) {
                $('body').append(data);
            }
        });
 </script>
```

But it does not work in firefox, in firefox not happens anything but in IE it worked.
when I write exact name of page for example `url: "getdata.php"` it work perfectly but with absolute address is not :( Why it doesn't work in firefix? any idea?
thanks for your help ...

Comment: Probably a same origin policy violation but I'm not sure why only Firefox. Are you browsing `http://mysite.com/` in Firefox (no `www`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP script returns error/nothing when fetching data with AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855249/php-script-returns-error-nothing-when-fetching-data-with-ajax)

Answer (score 2):

It's a security restriction of Firefox not to allow cross-domain Ajax requests.

Comment: Make sure you are pointing at a PHP document that is located on your server or localhost. It cannot be a subdomain either. It has to be in a sub or main folder for it to work

Comment: If you search Google for Firefox cross domain ajax there's quite a bit about it. Jonah's solution is best if possible, if you really need cross domain look into JSONP too.